# how to take average count of columns from multiple files using shell?

Tags: shell

I have 3 files each having 4 columns each, i want to take count of columns of each file and divide by total number of files, thus get the average column count from multiple files.

note- column count of each file may not be same each time and number of files can increase.
kindly help

```
eg - 
file1 = 3 columns
file2 = 4 columns
file3 = 5 columns

sum(3+4+5)/3(file count)= avg column count for directory having multiple files.
```

Comment: check out https://superuser.com/questions/256023/can-i-do-basic-maths-in-bash

Comment: Thanks for your input @AndyRay, but here i want to start from getting the column count of each file then sum up all and divide by count of files. that is my major roadblock. can u suggest how i can code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code snippet if you want. It is a bit elaborative to explain everything in detail.

The location contains 3 files

```
 1  #!/bin/bash

 2

 3  fileCount=`ls -lrt file*.txt | wc -l` ##take the count of number of files in the location

 4

 5  for file in ./file*.txt; do     ##running loop over the list of files individually. "file" is a parameter which'll reppresent each file

 6          temp=`awk -F"," '{print NF}' ${file} | uniq`    ##storing the column count in "temp" variable. Assumed each row has an entry

 7          columnCount=$(($columnCount + $temp))   storing and adding column count from each file

 8  done

 9

10  avgColumn=$(( columnCount / fileCount ))    ##Calculating average
11  echo "Files in directory `pwd` are having ${avgColumn} columns on average!"     ##Printing the average
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- `files=(file*.txt); fileCount=${#files[@]}`

Comment: Use `$(...)` instead of backticks -- see
https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006

Comment: For future answers, please exclude line numbers: it makes it harder to cut and paste.

Comment: While my tone may sound harsh, my intent is a friendly code review.

Comment: i don't mind at all. Thanks for the inputs.
I used `ls` assuming that it'll be better to have the code in easier syntax, albeit a bit generic.

Comment: @Salva You can use `find` as well if what glenn suggested in first comment is a bit hard to understand.